# Strings which contain logical operators

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a string and want to parse it so see if some element of the string exist within an array. Ex:

```
"Bob & Mary | (Michael & (Tim | !Jennifer ))" in names_list
```

I want to parse this string so I can make operations with it. In the example mentioned above, the results (in python) would be

```
"Bob" or "Mary" or ("Michael" and ("Tim" or not "Jennifer")) in names_list
```

which would result in True or False depending on which names exist in names_list.
Notice that the keywords:

`and`, `or`, `not` ...etc

are valid words in python

How can I take the result and use it in python?

EDIT: The names in the example string given may or may not be in an example list called names_list. After parsing the string, we'd be able to compare it with names_list (again, this is just an example list of names)

Comment: What do you mean by "use it in Python"?  Every non-empty string has a True value, so your example up there will return `"Bob"`.

Comment: Note that the result of the expression `"Bob" or "Mary" or ...` is just `"Bob"`.  It looks suspiciously like you're trying to implement some kind of query, which you can't actually do by just translating the symbols into Python operators.  What are you trying to query against?

Comment: The robust way is to write a parser from the ground up. A less robust way could be to use the `ast` module to have Python do the work for you, but you would need to pre-transform that `!` to `not`...

Comment: [parsing in python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing)

Comment: Probable [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
Bob = True
Mary = True
Michael = True
Tim = False
Jennifer = True

string_to_parse = "Bob & Mary | (Michael & (Tim | Jennifer ))"

print(eval(string_to_parse))
```

output:
`True`

Comment: Don't recommend `eval`. `string_to_parse = "__import__('os').system('evil-command-here')`